# How to parse string format "22Feb2023" to date in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a varchar field with dates in the format such as "10Jun2022". How can I convert to a date?

I tried like this but got an error:

```
select to_date(this_date, 'DDMMMYYYY') from my_table;

Can't parse '10Jun2022' as date with format 'DDMMMYYYY'
```

This is in Snowflake but maybe there's a general solution that applies elsewhere.

Comment: It is a bad idea to store dates as strings and I suggest you change this. What human language are you using to store the dates? Do you store December as 'DEC', 'DEZ', 'DIC', or something else still? What langauges are supported by the DBMS or the session? (I don't know whether this conversion depends on database or session settings in snowflake.) By storing dates as strings you can get undesired behavior in queries, so don't.

Comment: I'm actually importing from a CSV. We don't store dates like this. Our environment is pretty clean.

Answer (score 1):

The date format mask you need is `DDMONYYYY`:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(this_date, 'DDMONYYYY')
FROM my_table;
```

From the [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion#label-date-time-format-conversion) on date and time conversion functions:

> MON
> Full or abbreviated month name.